# Не работает функция с циклом for в Python

Tags: python, функции, циклы, for

Я новичок. Очень прошу Вашей помощи.

Есть цикл:

```
for dictionary in formattedData:
    if "stock_id" in dictionary:
        stock_id.append(dictionary["stock_id"])
```

Все работает. Список stock_id выводится корректно, со всеми нужными элементами. Заранее объявил переменную stock_id = [] .

Пытаюсь его оформить в функцию:

```
def values(keyname, data):
    for i in data:
        if str(keyname) in i:
            keyname.append(i[str(keyname)])
    return keyname
```

После `values(stock_id, formattedData)`
вывожу stock_id - он пустой.

Укажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка, чтобы я понимал. Бьюсь уже целый день. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: добавь в вопрос полный фрагмент кода с функцией и тем, как ты ее вызываешь. И исправь заголовок вопроса. Потому что цикл for в функции, разумеется, работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, так не получится. Объекты не знают, как называется переменная, которой присвоили ссылку на них. И `str` делает не то, что вы пытаетесь сделать, это не `nameof` из `C#`:

```
stock_id = []
print(str(stock_id))
```

Вывод:

```
[]
```

Вам придётся в явном виде указывать и объект и название ключа словаря, хотя вам и кажется, что они по виду одинаковые и должно быть легко получить одно из другого:

```
def values(lst, keyname, data):
    for i in data:
        if keyname in i:
            lst.append(i[keyname])
    return keyname
```

Вызывать, соответственно, так:

```
result = values(stock_id, "stock_id", formattedData)
```

Но вообще если вы тут "с нуля" формируете этот список, то вам его и не нужно вообще передавать в функцию, просто сформируйте *списковое сокращение* и присвойте в нужную переменную:

```
def values(keyname, data):
    return [i[keyname] for i in data if keyname in i]

stock_id = values("stock_id", formattedData)
```

P.S. Вернее, в питоне всё же есть способы узнать имя переменной во время выполнения кода, но они [не такие уж тривиальные](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64182077/getting-name-of-a-variable-in-python).
P.P.S. Вы можете сделать словарь с результатами и работать в нём со списками по вашему ключу, никто не заставляет вас использовать отдельные переменные:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def values(result, keyname, data):
    for i in data:
        if keyname in i:
            result[keyname].append(i[keyname])

result = defaultdict(list)
values(result, "stock_id", formattedData)
values(result, "что-то_ещё", formattedData)
print(result)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за подробное объяснение! Теперь мне все понятно, почему не работало. Естественно сейчас все заработало.

Comment: "P.P.S. Вы можете сделать словарь с результатами и работать в нём со списками по вашему ключу, никто не заставляет вас использовать отдельные переменные:" - спасибо за новый способ. Обязательно почитаю про defaultdict и попробую поэкспериментировать.